# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'index,django'

Tags: python, django

my project name = portfolio
my app name = index

**index - url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from index import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('home', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('project', views.project, name='project'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

**portfolio url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls'))
]
```

**and views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')
def project(request):
    return render(request, 'project.html')
def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

**and setting.py**

[INSTALLED_APPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFXfs.png)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'index',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I'm new to django. sorry. always gives this error in virtual or normal environment.

```
 File "C:\Users\Aytek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'index'
```

file tree:

[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFXfs.png)

Comment: Likely the problem is with the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Can you [edit] the question with this setting?

Comment: I added a photo. everything is normal.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: your `INSTALLED_APPS` has a typo, it is `'index',`, not `'index,'`

Comment: I edited but the error still persists.

Comment: you forgot a comma (`,`) at the end: the comma still should be there, but *after* the `'`.

Comment: share the file tree.

Comment: I understood and edited. it gives error again. I added error output.

Comment: I added the file tree.

Comment: The `index` directory should be moved in the *outer* `portfolio` directory, so `portfolio/index`.

Comment: it's fixed now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First try saving your settings.py file and see if the error goes.
or else try adding the whole path, 'index.apps.IndexConfig', instead of just 'index', in your settings.